# Updating SQL throws Exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to update an entire row on my sqlite database on android. But for some reason is throwing an exception.

The method that updates my Database is :

```
public void updateEvent(long rowId,Evento evento){
        int row=(int)rowId;
        ContentValues eventValues=createContentValues(evento);
        db.update(TABLE,eventValues,KEY_ROWID+"="+row,null);
    }
```

The createContentValues method is this:

```
private ContentValues createContentValues(Evento evento){
        ContentValues val=new ContentValues();
        val.put(KEY_ROWID,evento.getIdEvento());
        val.put(KEY_SUMMARY,evento.getSummario());
        val.put(KEY_DAY,evento.getFecha().getDia());
        val.put(KEY_MONTH,evento.getFecha().getMes());
        val.put(KEY_YEAR,evento.getFecha().getAnho());
        val.put(KEY_STATUS,evento.getStatus());
        val.put(KEY_NOTES, evento.getNota());
        return val;
    }
```

and the method that calls the update method is :

```
private void acceptAction(Evento evnt,String note){
        DbAdapter dbConn=new DbAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
        evnt.setNota(note);
        try{
        dbConn.updateEvent(evnt.getIdEvento(), evnt);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Error al Actualizar tu Evento", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.e("Error Candelaria", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The Log Entry line is commented because the Exception object doesn't contains any information, i can't do a `printStackTrace()` because println throws a NullPointerException.

UPDATE:
Logcat:

```
04-19 13:53:15.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4934): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 13:53:15.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at com.siitne.candelaria.data.DbAdapter.updateEvent(DbAdapter.java:48)
04-19 13:53:15.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at com.siitne.candelaria.ImportantList.acceptAction(ImportantList.java:130)
04-19 13:53:15.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at com.siitne.candelaria.ImportantList.access$3(ImportantList.java:126)
04-19 13:53:15.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at com.siitne.candelaria.ImportantList$1$1.onClick(ImportantList.java:113)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting in logcat?

Comment: `println` doesn't work in android. You can get the full stracktrace from logcat

Comment: don't getting any error, so i don't know what is wrong with the code - but my table isn't being updated and when tries to update catch an exception that shows the Toast Message.

Comment: Are you missing the end quote after row in db.update ?

Comment: i have deleted the quote after "row" because is an integer. - LogCat added on question :)

Comment: The line 48 on updateEvent is ' db.update(TABLE,eventValues,KEY_ROWID+"='"+row,null);
'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming   KEY_ROWID is integer you don't need single quote.

```
db.update(TABLE,eventValues,KEY_ROWID+"="+row+"",null);
```

IF not integer then

```
db.update(TABLE,eventValues,KEY_ROWID+"= '"+row+"'",null);
```

You don't need to print stacktrace. There is a view called Logcat. That will show complete error stacktrace.

EDIT: It is NullpointerException, not sqlexception. You need to make sure **db** is not null as well **evento** also.

Answer (score 1):

KEY_ROWID+"='"+row

you are missing the enclosing '

should read

KEY_ROWID+"='"+row + "'"